# Linear regression estimator with unknown noise variance

Tags: regression, bayesian

I have a noisy linear regression model, $Y = X \beta + \epsilon$ with noise $\epsilon$ sampled from a normal distribution $N(O, \sigma)$, where $\sigma$ is unknown and in turn sampled from a uniform distribution $U(0,\rho)$.

What is the best way to estimate $\sigma$ conditioned on $\rho$ and the input data sequence $(x_i, y_i)$?

For example, given only the data $(x_i, y_i)$, the best solution is probably an unbiased estimator $\sigma^2_{\text{est}} = \frac{1}{n-d}\sum_{j=1}^n(y_j-\hat y_j)^2$,  where $\hat y_j$ is the least squares solution.

How does this solution solution changes if we take into account $\sigma\sim U(0,\rho)$ with a given $\rho$?

Simpler question, what is the best *single scalar* estimator for $\sigma$ for a given $\rho$? Empirically, it is slightly higher than $\rho/2$, but I can't explain why.

Comment: Under that setup $\epsilon$ has a pdf of $\frac{\Gamma \left(0,\frac{\epsilon^2}{2 \rho ^2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi } \rho }$ so you could construct a maximum likelihood estimate of $\rho$.  From what you've written don't you want to estimate the parameter $\rho=2E(\sigma)$ rather than a random variable $\sigma$?

Comment: Oh, I assume that $\rho$ is given. I want to estimate $\sigma$ as a function of $\rho$ and the data.

Comment: Good.  That (a specified value for $\rho$) should be added to your question. But if you know $\rho$, you know everything about $\sigma$.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks! Modified the question.

Given $\rho$, all I know is that $\sigma\sim U(0,\rho)$. Now, conditioned on observation sequence $(x_i, y_i)$, I should be able to estimate $\sigma$ better.

For example, as I said above, just from the data observation alone, I can construct an unbiased estimator from the ordinary least squares solution. 

The question is, can I improve that estimator if I know that $\sigma\sim U(0,\rho)$ for a given value of $\rho$?

Comment: Now I think I understand what you're saying:  you just have a single observation from $\sigma \sim U(0,\rho)$ (i.e., all $Y$ values are associated with just that single $\sigma$ rather than each observation having a independent value of $\sigma$).  And you want to estimate that particular value of $\sigma$.  Is that correct?  I still wonder about that because of your statement "Empirically, it is slightly higher than ρ/2" implies that you want $E(\sigma)$ which is just $\rho/2$ without the need for any data.

Comment: Yeah, all $Y$ have single $\sigma$ and I want to estimate that $\sigma$. 

By "Empirically, it is slightly higher than ρ/2", I meant that if I sample multiple $X\sim N(0,I)$, $w \sim N(0,I)$, $\sigma \sim U(0,\rho)$ and try to find what is the best single $\hat\sigma$ that works for various $X, w, \sigma$, it turns out that it is slightly larger than $\rho/2$, but I can't explain why and how to find it in a closed form